# how to mock apache-camel EL

Tags: unit-testing, junit, apache-camel, mockito

i have the following RouteBuilder.

```java
 public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {    

        @Override
        public void configure() {
            errorHandler(deadLetterChannel(errorHandlerEndpoint)
                    .maximumRedeliveries(1)
                    .redeliveryDelay(2000)
                    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));

        from(fromEndpoint).routeId("fetchPreprocessingResultFromMarklogicRoute")
         .setHeader("principal").method(principalService, "getPrincipal").id("getPrincipalServiceMethod") // put principal to header for latter use
         .multicast()
            .filter(xpath("//files[@ml-generated='true']"))
            .choice()
                    .when(PredicateBuilder.isEqualTo(constant(EPrincipal.VETCENTER.principal()), simple("${header.principal.principal.principal}")))
                        .log("Sending VetCenter preprocessing report...")
                        .inOnly(toVetCenterEmailNotificationEndpoint)
                    .when(PredicateBuilder.isEqualTo(constant(EPrincipal.OSTEOTHEK.principal()), simple("${header.principal.principal.principal}")))
                        .log("Sending Osteothek preprocessing report...")
                        .inOnly(toOsteothekEmailNotificationEndpoint)
                    .otherwise()
                        .log("Principal unknown. Don't sending a preprocessing report...")
                        .inOnly("direct:trash") // @ToDo: Write test
                .end()
                .inOnly(toCleaningPhaseDecisionEndpoint)
                .inOnly(deleteImportDirsEndpoint)
            .end();

        }
}
```

This is the JUnit-Test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:application-context-test.xml"}) 
public class FetchPreprocessingResultFromMarklogicRoute_Test extends CamelTestSupport{
    private RouteBuilder route;

    @Value("${fetchPreprocessingResultFromMarklogicRoute.fromEndpoint}")
    private String testFromEndpoint;

    @Value("${fetchPreprocessingResultFromMarklogicRoute.toCleaningPhaseDecisionEndpoint}")
    private String toCleaningPhaseDecisionEndpoint;
    @Value("${fetchPreprocessingResultFromMarklogicRoute.vetcenter.toEmailNotificationEndpoint}")
    private String toEmailNotificationVetCenterEndpoint;
    @Value("${fetchPreprocessingResultFromMarklogicRoute.osteothek.toEmailNotificationEndpoint}")
    private String toEmailNotificationOsteothekEndpoint;
    @Value("${fetchPreprocessingResultFromMarklogicRoute.deleteImportDirsEndpoint}")
    private String testDeleteImportDirsEndpoint;
    @Value("${fetchPreprocessingResultFromMarklogicRoute.errorHandlerEndpoint}")
    private String testErrorHandlerEndpoint;

    private MockEndpoint emailNotificationVetCenterMOCKEndpoint;
    @Mock
    private PrincipalService principalServiceMOCK; 

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        if(route == null){

            route = new MyRoute(
                    testFromEndpoint, 
                    toCleaningPhaseDecisionEndpoint,
                    toEmailNotificationVetCenterEndpoint,
                    toEmailNotificationOsteothekEndpoint,
                    testDeleteImportDirsEndpoint, 
                    testErrorHandlerEndpoint,
                    principalServiceMOCK);
        }
        return route;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        Principal principal = new Principal();
        principal.setPrincipal(EPrincipal.VETCENTER);

        Mockito.when(principalServiceMOCK.getPrincipal("anyIdentificator")).thenReturn(principal);
        super.setUp();
    }


    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException{
        InputStream resourceInputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("testdata/importreport/inc/import-log-Vetcenter.xml");
        String message = new Scanner(resourceInputStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        emailNotificationVetCenterMOCKEndpoint = getMockEndpoint(toEmailNotificationVetCenterEndpoint);

        emailNotificationVetCenterMOCKEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(message);
        // Herausforderung ist, die Datei aus dem  Verzeichnis ablesen und camel Regeln zu prüfen
        template.sendBody(testFromEndpoint, message);

        emailNotificationVetCenterMOCKEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

this is the snippet of Principal and enum EPrincipal:

```java
public class Principal {
    private EPrincipal principal;

    public EPrincipal getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }
    public void setPrincipal(EPrincipal principal) {
        this.principal = principal;
    }
}

public enum EPrincipal {
    VETCENTER("Vetcenter"), OSTEOTHEK("Osteothek");
    private final String principal;

    EPrincipal(final String principal)
    {
        this.principal = principal;
    }

    public String principal()
    {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

i don't know how to make a mock for this snippet:

```
.when(PredicateBuilder.isEqualTo(constant(EPrincipal.VETCENTER.principal()), simple("${header.principal.principal.principal}")))
```

more exact for this part:

```
simple("${header.principal.principal.principal}")
```

It is expression language and i have no idiea how to create a mock for it. Is there other solution to create a unit test for it?

very many thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Force `principalServiceMOCK` to return your desired test principal in `getPrincipal`.

Have a look at the following simplified example.

Interface:

```
public static interface PrincipalService {
    Principal getPrincipal(String id);
    Principal getPrincipal();
}
```

Test class:

```
@Mock
PrincipalService principalServiceMOCK;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Principal principal = new Principal();
    principal.setPrincipal(Type.VETCENTER);
    Mockito.when(principalServiceMOCK.getPrincipal(TEST_ID)).thenReturn(principal);
    Mockito.when(principalServiceMOCK.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal);
    super.setUp();
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(TEST_ID); // OK
    resultEndpoint.expectedHeaderReceived("principal1", Type.VETCENTER);
    resultEndpoint.expectedHeaderReceived("principal2", Type.VETCENTER);

    template.sendBody("direct:start", TEST_ID);

    resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:start")
                    .setHeader("principal1").method(principalServiceMOCK, "getPrincipal(${body}).getPrincipal()")
                    .setHeader("principal2").method(principalServiceMOCK, "getPrincipal().getPrincipal()")
                    .to("mock:result");
        }
    };
}
```

Please note that:

- if using the original service implementation and `constant` then the header is evaluated at configuration time (= `configure()` is invoked) and if using `method` at runtime (= `direct:start` is invoked).
- if using the mock service then the header is evaluated at configuration time for both cases.

Comment: so i did understand. The problem is the setting of Header. Peter, i have completed my PrincipalService with the method getPrincipal(). So now i have 

Mockito.when(principalMockService.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal); 


But to run time the Header("principal") return null

Comment: so i completed my MyRoute with 

class VetcenterPredicate implements Predicate{

Principal principal = exchange.getIn().getHeader("principal", Principal.class);

   if(principal!=null){

    return 

EPrincipal.VETCENTER.equals(principal.getPrincipal());

   }else{

    return false;

   }

}

and changed the route configuration regard of new class. I setted a brackpoint at the "if" and found that principal is null

Comment: now i have no idia to test it. How should i create the route to use a mock by setting the Header ?

Comment: if i use 

setHeader("principal", constant(principalService.getPrincipal())).id("getPrincipalServiceMethod") 
instead of 

.setHeader("principal").method(principalService, "getPrincipal")

it works. I can find the header. But method(principalService, "getPrincipal") dosn't work for my mock. How camel works in this case ?

Comment: @student.cologne This is strange. Please have a look at my simple small example and test if you get the same result.